# How to trigger an animation if a hyperlink on a different slide was clicked?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to know if it is possible, to trigger an animation on a particular slide, if a certain hyperlink on a different slide of the same presentation was followed.

---

**Background:**

Currently, I use PowerPoint2016 to create the slides for a [PowerPoint Karaoke game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerPoint_Karaoke). I have started with a selecting slide where five little icons represent each of the five slide sets, I have prepared. Each icon is a hyperlink to the first slide of the corresponding set.
After the slide set is finished, a slide with a hyperlink back to the selecting slide is shown and the corresponding icon is removed (achied via an animation that is triggered by clicking on the icon with the hyperlink).
As a final slide, I would now like to include a voting slide, that show all the icons of the slide sets, that were used throughout the game. To be precise: If three out of five slide sets were used, I would like the voting slide to only include these three icons instead of all five.
My idea was now to someow trigger an animation on the voting slide depending on which hyperlink was clicked during the game.

I would very much appreciate any idea on how I could achieve the above described behaviour, possibly also using a completely different approach. Please also let me know, if any information is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I was not able to figure out how to achive an animation trigger on a different slide than the animaion itself, I have been able to solve my problem using the following VBA code.

```
Option Explicit
Private Const VotingSlideAs Integer = 5
Private Const TargetSlideNumber As Integer = 3


Sub FirstIcon()
  Dim myPresentation As Presentation
  Dim mySlide As Slide
  Dim myImageBox As Shape
  Dim myTextBox As Shape

  Set myPresentation = ActivePresentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentaion.Slides.Item(VotingSlide)
  Set myImageBox = mySlide.Shapes.AddPicture("filename", msoCTrue, msoCTrue, 100, 100, 85, 85)

  With SlideShowWindows(1).View
         .GotoSlide (TargetSlideNumber)
  End With

End Sub
```

The above code is assigned to an icon on the selecting slide via `insert` `action`. 
Upon clicking on the icon, the code inserts the image `filename` at the specified position of the voting slide and triggers a jump to the slide spcified with `TargetSlideNumber` (beginning of the corresponding slide set). Repeating the analogous code for all the icons on the selecting slide finally leads to the desired behaviour.